# Apache RewriteCond to prevent infinite loop

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics for my website, it's working fine with pages, the problem is the mp3 files that I want to hit the counter when they are accessed directly.

I have a php file as follows:

```
<?php 

error_log("hiiiiiiiii--".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); // for testing
error_log("meeeeeeeee--".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]); // for testing
//header("location:".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

?>

<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            //GA code goes here
            window.location = ("<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and in my .htaccess in the root folder of the audio files:

```
#RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_NAME} !(counter) #Here is the problem
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.mp3$ /media/counter\.php [L]
```

the request redirects to the counter.php and redirects to the .mp3 file, BUT this makes an infinite loop as it's obvious. 
What I need is the  RewriteCond such that if http_refferer or script_name contains the name "counter" DOES NOT redirect to counter.php.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I need is the RewriteCond such that if http_refferer or script_name contains the name "counter" DOES NOT redirect to counter.php.

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !counter [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !counter [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+?\.mp3$ media/counter\.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks bro :) One more thing, I added `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !mp3 [NC]` because when still I got the infinite loop, and when I checked the log, the referrer was the mp3 file! that was strange but I solved it with adding that line.